# Is there a way to compare incoming JSON data with local JSON data?

Tags: json, api, search, compare

There's a website ([Scryfall](https://scryfall.com)) that searches all Magic: the Gathering cards ever printed and returns specific results (cards of a specific rarity/power/name, etc). I like the site but I only want to search amongst the cards I own personally.

So Scryfall have a search API that returns JSON results. I've made collection.json as a local JSON file with the data of my personal collection, so when I search Scryfall's API, it will return the JSON, compare that with my local JSON, and only display things that match in both on the front-end.

This is what I have so far:

```
async function fetchAsync (url) {
    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    return data
}

let collection = fetchAsync('./collection')

let scryfall = fetchAsync('http://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=ceratops&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name')

let results = JSON.parse(scryfall).data.filter(card => { return collection.includes(card.id) } )

results.forEach(function (card) {
        document.querySelector('.card').innerHTML += "<li>" + card.name + "</li>"
    })
```

I'm expecting that to output only the matching results on the front end but it's not doing that.

Comment: Please share some code that you have done so we can help you

Comment: This is what I have so far:  
  
`async function fetchAsync (url) {  
    let response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    return data
}

let collection = fetchAsync('./collection')

let scryfall = fetchAsync('http://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=ceratops&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name')

let results = JSON.parse(scryfall).data.filter(card => { return collection.includes(card.id) } )

results.forEach(function (card) {
        document.querySelector('.card').innerHTML += "<li>" + card.name + "</li>"
    })`

Comment: please add the code to the question, not in comment 

Comment: As well, as requested - and example of expected answer would be great

Comment: That's all done - thanks so much and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON.stringify** function to convert JavaScript Object in string & you can compare with your local json.

Check JSON.parse & JSON.stringify you will get the idea how to do that.

Comment: But then how do I actually compare the two and output the matches?

Comment: If u could share sample response that its gets easy to help u. If u elaborate in a better way.